# Use data from mysql in HTML row

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a web page where I am pulling data from a mysql database and I want to be able to check a checkbox and change information within the table. The way I am displaying the information is as follows:

```
<?php
    $get_tickets = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assignment 
                                JOIN technician 
                                ON assignment.TechID = technician.TechID
                                JOIN employee
                                ON assignment.EID = employee.EID
                                JOIN ticket
                                ON assignment.TickID = ticket.TickID
                                WHERE assignment.TechID = '$current_id'");

    echo "<table border='1' width=\"100%\" style=\"margin: 0px;\">";
    echo "<tr><td>Ticket Number</td>";
    echo "<td>First Name</td>";
    echo "<td>Last Name</td>";
    echo "<td>Phone</td>";
    echo "<td>Device</td>";
    echo "<td>Location</td>";
    echo "<td>Problem</td>";
    echo "<td>Time Stamp</td>";
    echo "<td>Completed</td>";
    echo '<td><form><input type="checkbox"/></form></td></tr>';

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($get_tickets))
    {
        $count = 1;
        $checkbox = "checkbox" . $count;

        echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $row2["TickID"];
        echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row2["fname"];
        echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row2["lname"];
        echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row2["phone"];
        echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row2["device"];
        echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row2["location"];
        echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row2["problem"];
        echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row2["time_date"];
        echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row2["completed"];
        echo "</td><td>";
            echo '<form><input type="checkbox" name=' . $row2["TickID"] . '></form>';
        echo "</td></tr>";    
    }
?>
```

There may be better ways to ouput the information, but I just want to be able to click the checkbox and take the data from the row associated with the checkbox and change part of it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: wrong way of building the checkbox. you probably want `<input ... name="rowID" value="$row[TickID]" />`. giving it the name of the record is pointless. you'd have no idea what to look for in PHP, e.g. `$_GET['what goes here?']` is hard to do if you have no idea what value to as the key. but `$_GET['rowID']` will always exist and be the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

`echo '<form><input type="checkbox" name=' . $row2["TickID"] . '></form>';`

for this:
`echo '<a href="process.php?id='.$row2["TickID"].'">'.$row2["fname"].'</a>';`

on the file process.php you will get the variable like this

```
<?php 
        echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```